# Java Spark Framework - request body lost after middleware

Tags: java, spark-java

I am using Spark framework for my application.

I have a middleware which checks (among other things) if the body is of JSON format:

```
    // Middleware
    before((req, res) -> {
        // Method check
        if (!req.requestMethod().equals("POST")) {
            halt(403, "{\"result\":\"ERR\",\"errMsg\":\"Only POST allowed!\",\"code\":403}");
        }
        // JSON Check
        JSONObject body_json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            body_json = new JSONObject(req.body());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            halt(403, "{\"result\":\"ERR\",\"errMsg\":\"No valid JSON!\",\"code\":403}");
        }
        // At this point (end of middleware) the request body is still unchanged !
    });
```

Then I have my normal function for processing POST requests:

```
post("/post_some_data", (req, res) -> {
     String body = req.body()           // This string is empty !!
     int length = req.contentLength();  // This remain unchanged       
});
```

But the request body suddenly becomes empty (other attributes and headers remain unchanged).

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/201) in the spark framework. Updating the library to the 2.1 version will solve this and all of the similar problems.